# Using audio/images stored on Firebase cloud storage in my scene on Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am currently working on an AR application, and there's a part where I want to display information about a certain geographical location by displaying the image and description of the place. I want to retrieve the image and description from Firebase but I am not sure how to do so. There is also another scene where I want to retrieve audio files from Firebase cloud storage to play in the scene.  I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to download a file from Cloud Storage. My recommendation would be to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6du3DUTIPI) outlining integration with Unity if you're just getting started.

You'll basically have three approaches though:

1. Download a [byte array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/download-files#download_to_a_byte_array) or [stream](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/download-files#download_via_a_stream) with the Unity SDK. This is probably preferred if you have space in-memory to hold it.

```
// Download in memory, make the max size reasonable for your game
reference.GetBytesAsync(long.MaxValue).ContinueWithOnMainThread((Task<byte[]> task) => {
  if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    byte[] fileContents = task.Result;

    // this is needed for Unity
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    tex.LoadImage(fileContents);
  }
});
```

2. [Download to a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/download-files#download_to_a_local_file), load it later

```
// Create local filesystem URL
string local_url = $"file://{Application.persistentDataPath}/imageName.jpg";

// Download to the local filesystem
reference.GetFileAsync(local_url).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
    if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.Log("File downloaded.");
        // load from disk later
    }
});
```

3. [Download from a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/download-files#download_from_a_url), this generally isn't recommended but can offload some work to Unity.

```
reference.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread((Task<Uri> task) => {
  if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result());
    // ... now download the file via WWW or UnityWebRequest.
  }
});
```

4. ignore the Cloud Storage SDK entirely, and just grab the "public URL" from the console. Use Unity's [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTexture.html) to pull it down.